# when are the linux bin files built?

Tags: filesystems, compiling

I've a vendor-supplied Linux/arm kernel image burned into onboard NAND flash. However it seems that it's a very scaled down Linux with min. bin commands. Common commands like 'make' is unavailable.

So do I need to recompile a new Linux kernel or a new filesystem? Are the binary files built when compiling the filesystem (e.g. yaffs2) or the Linux image?

Comment: `make` is not part of the kernel but an external application package.  The vendor probably had **many** reasons not to include it along with plenty other utilities present on normal Linux distributions.  You might at least tell us what you're actually trying to achieve and the hardware used to see if it's reasonably feasible and how.

Comment: i'm developing some video processing related applications on a ARM-based SoC. I'm using Qt creator as my IDE for development works on a host Ubuntu PC. Previously I've tried to configure Qt 5 for my target architecture but it seems that there're a lot of errors which i'm unable to resolve. Therefore, I thought probably configuring, building and installing Qt 5 on the target embedded board itself would help to reduce the chances of error. However Qt configuration build-up requires 'make' function and is not available in the default Linux kernel image supplied by the vendor.

Comment: basically i'll be developing the GUI applications as well as the embedded software portions, responsible for processing and playback of H264 videos

Comment: If you are developing for, say, an embedded system, you usually cross-compile everything. That's both faster and more convenient. So things like `make` are not needed on the target system. You should make sure you've got matching libraries when you cross-compile, though.

Comment: i see. so assuming the Linux kernel image, fs and uboot is functional, i should be working on the application layer instead (i.e. via Qt Creator IDE), and then install the cross-compiled Qt lib as well onto my embedded target board?

Comment: actually are the binaries in e.g. /bin compiled during kernel compilation or during filesystem compilation?

Comment: Your question seems irrelevant to your problem and doesn't make that much sense.  The binaries could be compiled before, during and after the kernel compiling.  As for the filesystem, it is not something that gets compiled apart from the kernel component/module which is done with the kernel compiling normally.